# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to identify a button in a 3 Step - dialog, so same 'Next' button need to be clicked in first 2 steps of dialog, When used same xpath for first step, which works fine, but failing in step 2.

My Python Code:

```
a=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='create-portal-popup']/div[4]/div[1]/button[3]")
a.send_keys(selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.SPACE)
```

## The above code works and element is clicked.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
b=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='create-portal-popup']/div[4]/div[1]/button[3]")
b.send_keys(selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.SPACE)
```

## This fails with below exception.

Exception Observed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sabarish.kannan\workspace1\de.vogella.python.first\src\FirstModule.py", line 49, in <module>
    b=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='create-portal-popup']/div[4]/div[1]/button[3]")
  File "C:\Users\sabarish.kannan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 354, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\sabarish.kannan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 832, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\sabarish.kannan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\sabarish.kannan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='create-portal-popup']/div[4]/div[1]/button[3]"}
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64)
```

Comment: Please share the Url or html

Comment: Maybe a click on the button for the first time triggers a JS code that changes the HTML. You are using absolute xpath which may fail when the HTML changes.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to locate the element,then definitely there is some change with your DOM making your xpath invalid after you navigated to step-2.

1. Be sure of element you are trying to locate,dont just assume that both 'Next' button are same in step-1 and step-2.
2. Try using different locator method maybe using id/class/css/other selector methods,if you can find associated with 'Next' button in step-2.

Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 0):

We need to consider a few things here. As you mentioned `"When used same xpath for first step, which works fine, but failing in step 2"` is pretty correct. 3 separate elements can't have the same `xpath` at the same time on the `HTML DOM`.

1. Your first **`click()`** works because the **`xpath`** which is not unique matched the first **`Next`** button. I would suggest you to reconstruct the **`xpath`** of the first **`Next`** button to make it **`unique`**
2. A button is always expected to have an **`onClick()`** event which will change the **`HTML DOM`**. So when you invoke **`click()`** method, the **`HTML DOM`** changes. The reason is as stated above i.e. change in the **`HTML DOM`** due to presence of **`Javascript`** or **`Ajax Calls`**. So after the first **`click()`** is invoked we must try to construct a unique **`xpath`** for the second **`Next`** button again.
3. Similarly, for the reasons stated above you need to construct a unique **`xpath`** for the third **`Next`** button too.

Taking care of all these fact you will see away the error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```